rails - initialising a form value from parameter does not work?
I am rendering a simple form with a number field, trying to set the initial value of the field with a variable. If I use a constant in the ERB template it renders - if I set the value from a variable, it does not. ANy idea why?
Example code:
<%= f.label :share %>: <%= f.number_field :share, :step => 0.1, :value => @init_share %><br>

Processing by AuthorsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"init_share"=>"96.0", "work_id"=>"1"}

rendered HTML has no value field:
    <label for="author_share">Share</label>: <input step="0.1" type="number" name="author[share]" id="author_share" /><br>

However, this works:
<p> <%= link_to "FIX THIS (ADD AUTHOR)", new_author_path(:work_id => @work.id, :init_share => 96.0 ) %>

renders as
<label for="author_share">Share</label>: <input step="0.1" value="96.0" type="number" name="author[share]" id="author_share" /><br>

Seems like a simple issue, but why does using a parameter instead of a constant not work?

Does this answer your question? Rails: Keep params after a submit

no, it was just me using wrong identifier, as below. Thank you though!

OK, the answer was simple - I needed
params[:init_share]

in place of
@init_share

